# How to remove the dotted line around the link. I dont want to use outline:0 or none property

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have link, I just want to remove the dotted line around it. But, It should display dotted lines on focus. Is there any alternative way can we make It with out using outline:0 or none property.

Please let me know.

Comment: what's the issue with `outline: none`

Comment: when we use outline:none, on :focus the link is not highlighting, when we press the tab key the link should be highlighted.

Answer (score 3):

You can use following to your particular `<a href=""></a>` tag

```
a {
   outline: 0;
}
```

If link is not highlighting, add specific style to link on focus,

```
   /* unvisited link */
    a:link {
        color: #FF0000;
    }

    /* visited link */
    a:visited {
        color: #00FF00;
    }

    /* mouse over link */
    a:hover {
        color: #FF00FF;
    }

    /* selected link */
    a:active {
        color: #0000FF;
    }

   /* selected link */
    a:focus {
        color: #0000FF;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do using `online:none` on `a` tag

```
a,
a:focus,
a:visited {
    outline:none;
}
```